# Historical works to know why Buddhism diminished from India

Tags: reference-request, history, india

I am interested in knowing how buddhism diminished in India.

1 year back, I read this book:

https://books.google.co.in/books/about/History_Of_Hindu_Imperialism.html?id=51dWPgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y

But the author is not a historian.

Can you tell me references by Historians about how Buddhism diminished from India?

Comment: I closed this question as a duplicate of existing questions. Please see if the linked questions answer your question also.

Comment: Also from [history.SE] SE: [The decline of Buddhism in India around the 12th century](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/11556/29291)